# android kotlin shared preferences unresolved reference getSharedPreferences error

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am learning Kotlin by trying to build a small app that find and and remember last connected BLE device. To recognize the last connected device I decide to save its MAC address using shared preferences (is that the best way to do that is also a question). I use a tutorial online and it worked well (I didn't remember the page) but today when I open the project to continue the job it gives me error - unresolved reference getSharedPreferences. My question is what is the problem - I get lost :) Here is the class where I have the error row 23.

import android.content.Context

import android.content.SharedPreferences

interface PreferencesFunctions {

```
fun setDeviceMAC(deviceMAC: String)
fun getDeviceMAC(): String
fun setLastConnectionTime(lastConnectionTime: String)
fun getLastConnectionTime(): String
fun clearPrefs()
```

}

class PreferenceManager(context: ScanResultAdapter.ViewHolder) : PreferencesFunctions{

```
private val PREFS_NAME = "SharedPreferences"
private var preferences: SharedPreferences

init {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}

override fun setDeviceMAC(deviceMAC: String) {
    preferences[DEVICE_MAC] = deviceMAC
}

override fun getDeviceMAC(): String {
    return preferences[DEVICE_MAC] ?: ""
}

override fun setLastConnectionTime(lastConnectionTime: String) {
    preferences[LAST_CONNECTION_TIME] = lastConnectionTime
}

override fun getLastConnectionTime(): String {
    return preferences[LAST_CONNECTION_TIME] ?: ""
}

override fun clearPrefs() {
    preferences.edit().clear().apply()
}

companion object{

    const val DEVICE_MAC = "yyyyyyy"
    const val LAST_CONNECTION_TIME = "zzzzzzz"

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your arguement context is not a acitivity or fragment, and you need those two to call getSharedPreferences method.
`class PreferenceManager(context: Context) : PreferencesFunctions{`